# Why can't I create a div that has more than one style element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create div like so using jQuery:

```
let gridBlock = $("<div style=width:10px; height:20px; background-color:red;></div>");
```

However when I look at the render page the console shows that the div only has a style of width:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to quote the style value. Change it to `style='width:10px; height:20px; background-color:red;'`

Comment: Try `let gridBlock = $("<div style='width:10px; height:20px; background-color:red;'></div>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you have already got the answer in comment but there is a better way to implement using `class`. The reason [**css-specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Adding style using `style` attribute is hard to overwrite & need to use `!important` for that.

So to avoid that you can use the `class` attribute and define the style in css file

**some.css**

```
.someClass {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

in js file

```
let gridBlock = $("<div class='someClass'>Hello</div>");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rgxvy5uy/)

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes mate

```
let gridBlock = $("<div style='width:10px; height:20px; background-color:red;'></div>");
```